# iPhone :Can we add more than One application in a Single application

Tags: iphone

I do have an Idea to integrate with my application. I want to create multiple application within a single one application.

Like 
and application containing Weather application as well as image processing application + camera based application.

I want to know Is this thing possible with iphone application?

Please suggest me is this possible with iPhone app development and is it allowed by apple or not.

thanks for your suggestion in advance.

Comment: Regardless that the two applications don't seem to be related at all, you don't need two applications to have two different functionalities. You could do that with 2 UIViewControllers for example. Perhaps, you want to be more specific on why it has to be 2 apps and not 2 view controllers

Comment: Sure you can, but if you're going to give it a high price just for being a 3-in-1 thing, people will hate you for it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, you might get it approved. No, it is not a good idea. This will only lead to a hideous monstrosity of an application, which nobody in their right mind will want to use.

Comment: there are some apps like apptoolbox which are using the concept of the homescreen. But think this way: I better remember an app which does a thing (absolutely good) than an app with 1000 features. In the moment the user wont remember that this feature is too in this app. Here you can see what are the review guidelines to get your app successfully into the appstore: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: @iPhone can you tell me who is http://stackoverflow.com/users/493591/jagds to you and why this account re-asked this question?

Comment: @Will How would I know, it's a big community and any one can ask any question without searching the site of googling so it may possible of repeating questions.

Comment: @iPhone First, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646578/multiple-application-within-a-single-one-application a word-for-word repeat of this question.  Second, you share an ip; a static IP address used for broadband users in Chennai.  Quite the coincidence, you think?

Comment: @Will I came to know that My college posted the same question by copying my question  stackoverflow.com/users/493591/jagds is one of my college, I just asked him , so don't take it too serious.

Comment: @iPhone there was no evidence of vote fraud, so no mods were concerned. However, please ask him not to repost/repeat questions in future.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok @Will I'll take care of It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these things as features. Weather information is a feature, image processing is another and camera in another. You can create any number of features in your app. If that is what you have meant by application then that is technically possible and seems also OK with Apple. This is not 3 different applications, rather it's one application with three different features. No matter how many features you have, iOS will treat that as a single application(a single app bundle with a single executable file).

But if are asking whether there is any way to combine separate applications(separate projects, separate app bundles with separate executables) then that is not possible.

Note: Personally I think adding completely different features in a single app is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Go to App Store and search for this app, **App Tool Box - All in One**. It's exactly the same structure as you mentioned in your post. And it only costs $0.99.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it. I don't think Apple has anything against an app that does more than one thing. As long as none of those things breaks any of their rules.